# Saving collection of viewed elements in Unity / Vuforia

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have a scavenger hunt going where you find 9 different elements.  Only 4 have the special 'token'.  When you view the specific elements there is a token on the bottom of the screen that shows up as collected.  Problem is, I can't figure out how to save this using playerprefs so that you can collect all 4 tokens, even if you close out of the game.  Here is the token script

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using Vuforia;
using System.Collections;

public class token_icon : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{

```
private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

public GameObject token;
public GameObject lime_token;
public GameObject loconut_token;
public GameObject crown_token;
public GameObject gin_token;

void Start()
{
    mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
    if (mTrackableBehaviour)
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
    }
}

public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
{
    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED)
    {
        token.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        token.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Arrays. Arrays will probably help.

Answer (score 0):

The `PlayerPrefs` class only saves and loads data of types `int`, `float`, and `string`. To save the state of each token, you can cast the local `newStatus` enum to an int and use that as the value saved by `PlayerPrefs`. In addition, you should create new functions to save and load to and from `PlayerPrefs`. When loading back simply cast `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Key")` back to the `TrackableBehaviour.Status` enum. Here is the link to the documentation for `PlayerPrefs` in case you haven't seen it already: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

I modified your source code by adding two new functions to show how you could get started.

public class token_icon : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{

```
private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

public GameObject token;
public GameObject lime_token;
public GameObject loconut_token;
public GameObject crown_token;
public GameObject gin_token;

void Start()
{
    //Inserted Function
    LoadStatus();

    mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
    if (mTrackableBehaviour)
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
    }
}

public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
{
    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED)
    {
        token.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        token.SetActive(false);
    }
    //Inserted Function
    SaveStatus();
}

//Save to PlayerPrefs
private void SaveStatus()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Token", (int)newStatus);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}

//Load from PlayerPrefs
private void LoadStatus()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Token"))
    {
        TrackableBehaviour.Status loadStatus = (TrackableBehaviour.Status)PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Token");

        if (loadStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            loadStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED)
        {
            token.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            token.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Obviously this can be written in a more general fashion to work for more than just a single token GameObject, but I don't know enough about your workflow to make any guesses about the best way to go about that.